# Is it fine to "await" methods inside other "async" methods

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I want to understand is it good to call one awaitable method from another one. Will this cause any issues if "recursively" call methods using "await"?

```
async void AsyncMeth()
{
    await AsyncMeth2();
}
```

If this is not good, why and what should i do?
Thank you.

Comment: Can we see a full example?

Comment: It really depends on what you are doing with your meth.

Comment: This has been asked a few times, what about this one is different?

Comment: @TravisJ, you know, I was going to avoid making _crack_ comments, but the method name is just unfortunate.

Comment: @gunr2171 it is HTTP API implementation, where an network class with awaitable method for HTTP request base. Other API methods use this method and they're awaitable (async). Actually AsyncMeth2() parses responses and constructs requests, while AsyncMeth() uses it and processes the result data.

Comment: I am the one who awaits?  In seriousness, without more details it's hard to answer, but it sounds like you're experiencing the "zombie async" spread that Stephen Clearly points out:  *Others have also noticed the spreading behavior of asynchronous programming and have called it “contagious” or compared it to a zombie virus. Whether turtles or zombies, it’s definitely true that asynchronous code tends to drive surrounding code to also be asynchronous. This behavior is inherent in all types of asynchronous programming, not just the new async/await keywords.*

Comment: Why do you call this as "recursively"?

Comment: Calling a chain of async methods is fine, that isn't really recursion. Calling the same async method inside of your async method would be recursion. At which point you would continue by calling the same async method inside of your async method which would be recursion. Even if you do recurse in this fashion it essentially creates a queue of the tasks to operate on. As long as each one is being awaited there should be no deadlocking.

Comment: I am not using Task.Run or any other thing anywhere

Comment: When you await, you are awaiting something that returns a Task or a Task<T>

Comment: @TravisJ i am not an idiot.

Comment: @Yogee read as "Is it fine to await awaitable method from onother awaitable method" then :)

Comment: @DmitrijA - I am not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's perfectly fine to have one `async` method call another one.

In most cases, the returned `Task` is immediately `await`ed:

```
async Task MethAsync()
{
  await Meth2Async();
}
```